# Cocoapods podfile target adding frameworks to tests only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to modify my podfile to include pods for networking testing in the test target. This is what my podfile looks like:

```
target 'BPD-mobile' do
   # Used to simplify reads/writes to coredata
   pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.3.0'                 #obj-c
   pod 'MFSideMenu', '~> 0.5.5'                    #obj-c
   pod 'UIDevice-Hardware', '~> 0.1.7'             #obj-c
   pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK', '~> 7.1.1'                #obj-c
   pod 'AKNumericFormatter', '~> 0.0.2'            #obj-c
   pod 'JSBadgeView', '~> 1.3.2'                   #obj-c
   pod 'RETableViewManager', '~> 1.6'              #obj-c
   pod 'RNBlurModalView', '~> 0.1.0'               #obj-c
   pod 'APLKeyboardControls', '~> 0.1.3'           #obj-c
   pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'                 #obj-c
   pod 'RBStoryboardLink', '~> 0.1.4'              #obj-c
   pod 'DTCoreText', '~> 1.6.16'                   #obj-c

   # This pod is used for all networking requests
   pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'                  #obj-c
   pod 'MTMigration', '~> 0.0.5'                   #obj-c
   pod 'Harpy', '~> 3.3.10'                        #obj-c
   pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7.3'                    #obj-c
   pod 'ELCImagePickerController', '~> 0.2.0'      #obj-c
   pod 'UAAppReviewManager', '~> 0.2.6'            #obj-c
   pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet', '~> 1.7.2'               #obj-c

   # Used to report crashes to github and open issues for them
   pod 'Fabric'#, '~> 1.6.4'                       #obj-c
   pod 'Crashlytics'#, '~> 3.8.2'                  #obj-c

   pod 'DeepLinkKit', '~> 1.1.0'                   #obj-c

   # User for UI Layout and additional widgets
   pod 'Eureka', '~> 2.0.0-beta.1'                 #swift 3.0

   # Adds pull screen down for callback functionality, used to
   # sync with server
   pod 'PullToRefreshCoreText', :git => 'https://github.com/BigPurpleDot/PullToRefreshCoreText' #obj-c

   # Pods to only be used for this target
   target "BPD-mobile Tests" do

       # This pod is used to hijack http methods and respond with
       # pre recorded information
       pod 'OHHTTPStubs', '~> 5.2.3'

       # This pod is used to record http response data for reuse
       pod 'SWHttpTrafficRecorder', '~> 1.0.2'
   end
end
```

Notice I have the test target nested in the BPD-mobile target. When I try to compile this it says that the "Pods_BPD_mobile_Tests" framework isn't found. I looked at the pods folder in my project and this is what they look like:

'Pods-BPD-mobile',

'Pods-BPD-mobile-BPD-mobile Tests'

the 'Pods_BPD_mobile Tests' pod is in red. I'm assuming I need either the podfile to be structured in a way for the tests framework to output to 'Pods_BPD_mobile Tests' or I have to change some setting so it looks for the tests framework under the new path. What setting do I have to change/ how should my podfile look for my project to build?

EDIT:

The problem seems to be that there's a space in the name of the target:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3754

I don't quite understand the solution though, can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so this had nothing to do with my configurations and was a cocoapods error. Because my target has a space in the name I had to manually edit the scrips run for both the test target and the main target and add single quotes around "$1" turning it into: '"$1"' as per this github issue:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3754